# Way to digitally measure volume of air inhaled by lungs?

Tags: measurements, airflow

I was interested in this as a fun project. To be able to get the volume of air inhaled by a person has some cool applications I can think of.

I was thinking of a modified anemometer of sorts fitted in a tube that the person sucks / blows air through. Plotting the velocity of air against time and the area under the graph and multiplying that with the circumference of the tube would give volume of air inhaled?

Or

https://www.google.com/amp/s/makersportal.com/blog/2019/02/06/arduino-pitot-tube-wind-speed-theory-and-experiment%3fformat=amp

This sort of thing attached to a tube through which a person sucks / blows. Then using the same logic to get the volume of air.

Would either of these work? Are there better solutions?

Comment: Do some research on spirometers, which are the medical instruments used to measure this. Measuring the flow velocity in a pipe is one of the techniques that is used, so it will "work" if you get the details right.

Comment: And if you want to start looking at the "details" mentioned by alephzero, then velocity profile, turbulent flow, Reynolds number and boundary layer are all things to look up.

Comment: I have had to take a test doing exactly what you refer to. They had me run on a treadmill while hooked up to a mask on my mouth and nose and sensors attached to my chest and the computer monitor was recording my heart-lungs performance.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to build is called a spirometer, and there are already digital versions available.

Googling on the term should find you a wealth of information.